# Не удается манипулировать базой данных на сервере pythonanywhere

Tags: mysql, pythonanywhere

Не удается удаленно подключится к базе MySql и вставлять данные.
Постоянно выдает ошибку "Access denied for user".
Пытался задать права командой "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'user'@'localhost';", но и тут получил эту же ошибку (что и логично).
Других пользователей на pythonanywhere не имею.
Новичок в этой теме, помогите))

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен. Нужно было перед самой базой писать user$